# Sitecore Media File upload above 2GB throws Bad Request 400

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

we are on Sitecore 8.1 U3 , content editors generally upload large files to the media library using the File upload (advanced) option with Upload as files checked , these files are uploaded to a blob storage from the server

Sitecore Throws a 400 Bad request error at sitecore/shell/Applications/Media/UploadManager/Upload.aspx?db=master&id=%7B319E3E74-7251-46F8-xxxxxxxxxx%7, if the uploaded file is above 2GB

I have tried increasing the requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength value to 4GB and maxRequestLength to 4gb , does not work , throws the same error

I also read that IIS 7 and higher have a file upload limit of 2GB

Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 3):

#### No, you're not. 2 GB is the limit.

For a couple of reasons:

- requestFiltering doesn't allow to specify more than 4 GB for maxAllowedContentLength
- maxRequestLength is expressed in kilobytes and the limit specified above is nearly 2 TB. ASP.NET 2.0 doesn't allow a value greater than 2097151 KB (approx. 2 GB) and trying to set a greater value will fail with the following error : 
  "The value for the property 'maxRequestLength' is not valid. The error is: The value must be inside the range 0-2097151"
- If the application is running under the NET 4.5 Integrated Pipeline, upload will not work above 2G and the following error will be sent by IIS: "HTTP 400.0 – Bad Request ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL.".

Source: [Uploading large file to IIS 7.5 or 8 using file input element](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2013/06/19/uploading-large-file-to-iis-7-5-or-8-using-file-input-element/)

#### What you could consider

- Is uploading the file via an FTP connection to your server, and have Sitecore "pick it up". Default folder is `/upload`
- Using WebDAV. Admittedly I've not attempted this in years, but the WebDAV protocol should work around this limitation issue